# Fix font vertical alignment for iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, alignment, osx-elcapitan

We have a custom made font which we use on an iOS app. This font is displaced vertically respect the other fonts.

We usually used the ftxdumperfuser, but with the new El Capitan OSX release this app became incompatible.

So, is there any way to install this tool on El Capitan or is there any other tool to edit the ascender and descender of the font?

Comment: You could generate a new version of your custom font, with the metadata adjusted to effect a higher baseline on the quad, and then using that font for OSX releases.

Comment: Yes, but how? that's what I want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you can just use the same software that you used to make the font in the first place?

Comment: The situation is a bit more complicated, we do not create the font, the design studio creates it and they have no idea on how to do it... :/

Comment: How can you know how to create a font, but not know how to adjust alignments... I would question that design studio. Anyway, added an answer that addresses the problem.

Comment: A downvote? after so many time? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to tell the people who made the font for you to fix the baseline alignment.

But, if that isn't an option, the simplest way to achieve this is to add a (or modify the) [BASE table](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/base.htm) in your font, using whatever font editing tools you have available to you, for the scripts used in your font (if it's not specifically designed for non-western languages, that's typically just `latn`)

Tools like [TTX](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools) or [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io) are free, powerful, and require a bit of learning how to use them, tools like [Fontlab](http://old.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio) (currently on v5, we're all waiting for v6 to go on sale) are easier to use, but also "expensive".